# Changing number of rows in a DefaultTableModel after initialization

Tags: java, swing, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to instantiate a DefaultTableModel but I do not know how many rows I need when I initially create the object.  There is a "Read" button that the user presses, and after they have done so I want to then update the table with the data received from the read. So basically, when the program launches I create a new DefaultTableModel with null data

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null, columnNames);
```

I've also tried initializing with 0 rows:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = newDefalutTableModel(columnNames, 0);
```

Now I press a "Read" button, which triggers an action listener on one of my objects and updates the table with the data I now have. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
String[] columnNames = new String[]{"dataHeader1", "dataHeader2"};
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(); 
tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
```

When you have data you can use:

```
String[] columnNames = new String[]{"dataHeader1", "dataHeader2"};
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();


//you can do a for loop here...
Object[][] data= new Object[5][columnNames.length];
data[0][0] = "";
data[0][1] = "";

data[1][0] = "";
data[1][1] = "";
...

tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames);
```

Comment: The OP doesn't know how many rows of data he needs to you should not be using an Array for the data since you don't know how big to make the Array. Also, the DefaultTableModel will just copy the data from the Array to a Vector, so use a Vector right from the start and you don't need to worry about the size issue.

Comment: Well at first he dont know how many rows he needs but after the user press the button I was guessing he would knows. Thanks for the second tip.

Answer (score 0):

> but I do not know how many rows I need

Then create a Vector for every row of data that you read. Then you can just use:

```
model.addRow(...);
```